# How to show a link in every tr in a table

Tags: php, mysql

l have a php code that populates a table from a database. l echo all the data from the table into the table using this code

```
foreach ($m as $value=>$key){

    echo "<tr><td onmouseover = 'show()' onmouseout='hide()' >" . $key['name'] . "<a href='add.php' id='editlink'> Edit</a>" . "</td><td>" . $key['office_name'] . "</td><td>" . $key['description']  .  "</td><td>" . $key['image']  . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Javascript that is applied to the `editlink`

```
<script> 
function show() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("editlink").style.display = "inline"; 
} 
function hide()
{ 
    document.getElementById("editlink").style.display = "none"; 
} 
</script>
```

it works fine except that the edit link shows for only the first row in the table. how do l show the link in every row.thanks

Comment: How do you handle `edit` click event?

Comment: Would you want link over full row <tr>?

Comment: Do you have some JS that fiddles with the edit link after the page gets loaded? I ask because all your edit links will have the same `id='editlink'` and `id` is supposed to be unique on a page so the JS will not work properly

Comment: Try to add you edit link in new <td>

Comment: link is showing for every row.

Comment: Please provide an array named as $m.

Comment: _Just a note:_ `foreach ($m as $value=>$key)` should logically be `foreach ($m as $key=>$value)` as the first param is the array key and the second is the value of the data held in occurance[`$key`] ?!?

Comment: this is the edit click event <script>
 function show() {
    document.getElementById("editlink").style.display = "inline";
}
function hide(){
 
  document.getElementById("editlink").style.display = "none";
}
 </script>

Comment: ok..thanks @RiggsFolly.will correct that

Comment: @DharaParmar ..is it showing for every row in the table..

Comment: @RiggsFolly using class worked but cant seem to make my js work now

Comment: Try document.getElementsByClassName('editlink') in place of document.getElementById('editlink')

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName creates the edit link for every tr but the javascript code does not execute

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate row and modify your PHP into something like this:

```
    <?php

    $i = 1;

    foreach ($m as $value=>$key) {

        echo "<tr onmouseover = 'show(".$i.")' onmouseout='hide(".$i.")'><td>" . $key['name'] . "<a href='add.php' id='editlink".$i."'> Edit</a>" . "</td><td>" . $key['office_name'] . "</td><td>" . $key['description']  .  "</td><td>" . $key['image']  . "</td></tr>";

        $i++;
    }
```

And the JavaScript should be like this:

```
    <script> 
    function show(i) { 
       document.getElementById("editlink"+i).style.display = "inline"; 
    } 

    function hide(i) { 
       document.getElementById("editlink"+i).style.display = "none"; 
    } 
    </script>
```

Comment: your answer does not work. the edit link is generated for each tr but the javascript functions does not work..

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, you can check working version here on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/azpso4wj/8/

Answer (score 0):

l found a way to do it. l used document.getELementsByClassName to return a nodelist of all tr then looped throught the list to insert an edit link..code will explain better

```
                                   <?php 
$m =  edit_keymember();

if(!(is_array($m))){

    echo "not array";
}

foreach ($m as $value=>$key){

    echo "<tr><td onmouseover = 'show()'  onmouseout='hide()' >" . $key['name'] . "<a href='add.php' class='editlink' > Edit</a>" . "</td><td>" . $key['office_name'] . "</td><td>" . $key['description']  .  "</td><td>" . $key['image']  . "</td></tr>";

}

?>

Javascript

<script>
    function show() {
        var i;
        var len = document.getElementsByClassName("editlink");
        for ( i = 0 ; i <= len.length ; i++){

         len[i].style.display = "inline";

        }
}
function hide(){
    var i;
        var len = document.getElementsByClassName("editlink");
        for ( i = 0 ; i <= len.length ; i++){

         len[i].style.display = "none";

        }
}
    </script>
```

am a newbie developer l am gratefull for all suggestions and will ask more soon..lol..thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think that this will work fine :

```
<?php
foreach ($m as $key => $value) { ?>
<tr>
<td onmouseover = 'show()' onmouseout='hide()'> <?php $key['name'] ?> <a href='add.php' id='editlink'> Edit</a> </td>
<td> <?php $key['office_name'] ?> </td>
<td> <?php  $key['description'] ?> </td>
<td> <?php $key['image'] ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not going to make any difference I am afraid ___(Not my DV)___

Comment: yes i know that but sometimes stupid changes in code make it happen :D

Comment: @HamzaTorjmen l dont see any difference between your answer and my previous code that doesn't achieve the result.